# Decimal to hex string

Tags: php

I have a decimal value of a utf-32 character:

```
$a=21644;
```

How can I convert this using php to a **string** of the hex? `'548c'`

Here is the page for the codes I am using:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/548c/index.htm

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/es/function.dechex.php `dechex()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`dechex`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) is what you need here:

```
php > echo dechex(21644);
548c
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `dechex`:

```
$hex = dechex($decimal);
```

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)